# Deleting Data In Web API from MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have been making a project which involves a Web API and MVC, I have been able to connect my MVC project to my API allowing me to display data onto one of my views using a table.
I am struggling to create a delete function on my MVC project, I have made it pull a set of data from the table to a different view using the ID (i have created the view using the template you are given)
The code below is what I did in order to get that data

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{

StudentModel Student = new StudentModel();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6193/");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/students/" + id).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Student = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<StudentModel>().Result;

}
return View(Student);

}
```

Now I am trying to use the [HttpPost] to remove the data from my database I would be really grateful if anyone is able to help me out and keep it pretty simple so I am able to understand it. Could you also explain what your code is doing so I can use it in the future

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? How is your Web API defined? What function on your web service are you trying to call?

Comment: The code which i just pasted in works fine that is just collecting the data i am now trying to make a [httppost] method which deletes the data that the [httpget] method just got for me. My web api works fine i can view the data from my mvc view but i want to add the delete fuction onto that view.

Comment: So I assume you have some client (probably a web client) calling this MVC `Delete` method which in turn calls to your Web Api at http://localhost:6193/api/students/1234. Am I correct?